# Bug in Perl or I don't understand something about regexp matching and perl variables?

Tags: perl

For long time, I was always thinking that parameters in Perl subs are passed by value. Now, I hit something that I don't understand:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

sub p {
    print STDERR "Before match: " . Data::Dumper->Dump([[@_]]) . "\n";
    "1" =~ /1/;
    print STDERR "After  match: " . Data::Dumper->Dump([[@_]]) . "\n";
}

my $line = "jojo.tsv.bz2";

if ($line =~ /\.([a-z0-9]+)(?:\.(bz2|gz|7z|zip))?$/i) {
    p($1, $2 || 'none');
    p([$1, $2 || 'none']);
}
```

On first invocation of p(), and after executing of regexp match, values in @_ will become undefs. On the second invocation, everything is OK (values passed as array ref are not affected).

This was tested with Perl versions 5.8.8 (CentOS 5.6) and 5.12.3 (Fedora 14).

The question is - how this could happen, that regexp match destroys content of @_, which was built using $1, $2 etc (other values, if you add them, are not affected)?

Comment: I'm tending towards the "I don't understand something" option :-)

Comment: Could you be more clear? Where exactly does @_ become undef?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [perlsub man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) says:

> The array @_ is a local array, but its elements are aliases for the actual scalar parameters.

So when you pass `$1` to a subroutine, inside that subroutine `$_[0]` is an *alias* for `$1`, not a *copy* of `$1`.  Therefore it gets modified by the regexp match in your `p`.

In general, the start of every Perl subroutine should look something like this:

```
my @args = @_;
```

...or this:

```
my ($arg1, $arg2) = @_;
```

...or this:

```
my $arg = shift;
```

And any capturing regexp should be used like this:

```
my ($match1, $match2) = $str =~ /my(funky)(regexp)/;
```

Without such disciplines, you are likely to be driven mad by subtle bugs.

Comment: +1, especially for the suggestion to assign regex captures to named variables rather than using `$1` and its brethren.

Comment: Using "my @args = @_" could be a performance loss, and Perl is already slow enough. OTOH, in non-critical places it would be easier to simply do "@_ = @_" - this will get rid of aliases without need to introduce additional variable (this is what I did in my case).

Comment: You have my personal guarantee that copying a short args list to a new array is the least of your optimization worries. `my @args = @_` is good practice and not a significant bottleneck.

Comment: Yes, I know. Usually, I do `my @parm = shift` for all arguments, and moving the rest in some other array, but in few cases I want to optimize things. In my real application, p() is something that takes many arguments and executed often enough to worry about this (result of profiling, not guess) - and it was first time when I passed $1 directly.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested, copying the args in every sub is a good idea (if only to document what they are by giving them a non-punctuation name).

However, it's also a good idea to never pass global variables; pass `"$1", "$2"`, not `$1, $2`.   (This applies to things like `$DBI::errstr` too.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why this happens but I would say you should use something like
    my $arg1 = shift;
    my $arg2 = shift;
and use $arg1 and $arg2 in your sub.

Using the perl debugger you will see that @_ looks different in the 2 sub calls:

1st call: Before match:

```
x @_
0  'tsv'
1  'bz2'
```

After match:

```
x @_
0  undef
1  undef
```

I think this was overwritten by the match.

2nd call: Before match:

```
x @_
0  ARRAY(0xc2b6e0)
    0  'tsv'
    1  'bz2'
```

After match:

```
x @_
0  ARRAY(0xc2b6e0)
    0  'tsv'
    1  'bz2'
```

So maybe this wasn't overwritten because of the different structure(?).

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Sure @_ looks different - it was intentional for demonstration purposes. To be honest, I completely forgot about @_ aliasing, as I never had problem of this kind before - and now I'll be more careful.